# how to append one notebook at the end of another

Tags: notebooks

I developed and tested two pieces of a new program separately from older programs. For this it wasn't too bad to copy and paste old cells and test as I went. But now I have the two sizeable program pieces to combine, and copy and pasting one line by line to the end of the other will be tedious and somewhat error prone.

Would anyone know a way to do this more simply please

Comment: Edit > Select All, Edit > Copy, switch notebook, Edit > Paste?

Comment: On my Mac, I would just use Cmd+a then Cmd+c and finally, in the other notebook, Cmd+v. (i.e. keyboard version of what Michael E2 wrote.)